# Call reversed MotionLayout animation in fragment when pressed "physical" Back button on device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-motionlayout

I set a `MotionLayout` transition in my fragment when it is shown in activity and I also have a back button on top of the fragment which reverse that transition before doing `onBackPressed` in activity and everything look smooth and lovely.

I simply call in my button's `onClickListener`:

```
binding.root.transitionToStart()
```

And in dedicated `TransitionListener` I just call appropriate method in viewModel to propagate information to activity to call `onBackPressed`:

```
private val transitionListener = object: MotionLayout.TransitionListener{
    override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int) {}

    override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) {}

    override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
        if (currentId == R.id.start) {
            mainViewModel.moveToHomeScreen() // <-- notify ViewModel
        }
    }

    override fun onTransitionTrigger(...) { }
}
```

I would also like to show that reversed animation when pressing "physical" **Back** button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described I believe you're running the transition and then calling `onBackPressed`, but instead you should consider overriding `onBackPressed`, detecting whether you need to run the transition, and if you don't allow the call to `super.onBackPressed`.

```kotlin
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (isDetailStateShown()) {
        exitDetailState()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Since you're dealing with an Activity and Fragment you'll need a way to communicate from your Activity to your Fragment the request for state as well as sending the command to exit.

One last thing - if you're depending on `MotionLayout.currentState`, note that it will respond with a value of `-1` if it is not fully in one state or another. The fact you're checking `currentState` against `R.id.start` already means you're already handling this, just wanted to point it out in case you add more states. And if you do add additional state, `exitDetailState` will need to not simply run `transitionToStart`, but instead have logic for which transition to run and what state to goto.